# RoutePrefixAttribute doesn't have a RouteOrder property?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, attributerouting

I want to use this `RouteOrder` optional property of `[RoutePrefixAttribute]` described here:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#order

In order to resolve ambiguous controller selection problems. The problem is, I can't find such a property at all (no intellisense, doesn't compile)! I'm using

System.Web.Http.RoutePrefixAttribute

from assembly System.Web.Http.dll, v5.2.0.0 (packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core.5.2.0\lib\net45\System.Web.Http.dll)

Is it the wrong one? Or are the docs just wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `RouteOrder` parameter doesn't apply on the `RoutePrefix` attribute. It only applies to the `Route` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Only `[RouteAttribute]` has the RouteOrder property.

In Web API 2.2 there is no way to set a 'default' RouteOrder for all your controllers route by putting a RouteOrder on your `[RoutePrefixAttribute]`.

Comment: `RoutePrefix` attribute doesn't add any routes to the route table by itself, only `Route` attributes do...so that's the reason `RoutePrefix` doesn't have a Order property